# Passing objects as parameters in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

How do I pass an object to a private sub as a reference in Excel VBA? Below is what I am trying to do:

```
Sub main()
    Dim r As Range
    Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(27, 27))
    r.Select 'this works
    select_cells (r) 'this doesn't work
End Sub

Private Sub select_cells(a As Range)
    a.Select 'prompts Object Required error
End Sub
```

Comment: try `call` in front of `select_cells`: `call select_cells (r)` worked for me on a local test

Answer (score 10):

> ```
> select_cells (r) 'this doesn't work
> ```

You can't use parentheses to pass object parameters to a procedure. Just do this:

```
select_cells r
```

The archaic, obsolete `Call` keyword can be used, if you *really* want to keep the parentheses.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why should avoid parentheses when passing Object as parameter?

Comment: @HowToTellAChild objects can (and a lot *do*!) have *default properties* - parentheses are forcing the evaluation of an expression, so what the procedure gets isn't the intended object but its default property. Usually that causes a *type mismatch* error, but things can get ugly/tricky with `Variant` parameters. Drop the parentheses, they're not just "for readability" - they change the meaning of your code. For non-object arguments, they're purely redundant.

Comment: If the object doesn't have a default member, then VBA fails with an error that means "I can't find that member", and execution stops.

Answer (score 6):

There are severla errors in your code

1. Unqualified range references refer to the `ActiveSheet`.  So

   ```
   Set r = Sheets("Sheet1").Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(27, 27))
   ```

   will error if `Sheet1` is not active.
2. `r.Select` will error if `Sheet1` is not active.
3. `select_cells (r)` with the brackets is incorrect.  Use

   ```
   select_cells r
   ```
4. `a.Select` in the Private Sub will error if `Sheet1` is not active.

Here's an modified version

```
Sub main()
    Dim r As Range
    With Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set r = .Range(.Cells(1, 1), .Cells(27, 27))
    End With
    Debug.Print r.Address ' for diagnostic purposes
    select_cells r
End Sub

Private Sub select_cells(a As Range)
    ' Activate the worksheet first, so you can select a range on it
    a.Worksheet.Select
    a.Select
End Sub
```

---

Note on bracketed parameters

When a `Sub` or `Function` parameter is a non-object variable, bracketing the parameter overrides the `ByRef`/`ByVal` definition and passes the parameter `ByVal`

When a `Sub` or `Function` parameter *is* an object variable, bracketing the parameter causes an the default property to be passed to the `Sub`/`Function`.   In the case of the OP, this is `r.Value`, which causes a type missmatch.

Comment: "passing an Object by value has no meaning" That's not really true - most events pass objects ByVal, for example. It just means you pass a *copy* of the pointer, not the original pointer. Using the parens forces the compiler to try and evaluate the default property of the object and pass that result-which may be an object or data type.