# Passing PPTX Shape as Variable Fails on "Object does not support this property or method"

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

This routine runs within Excel VB. It fails at the point indicated with the message indicated. This is stripped-down code.  I've tried many variations. Seems like it ought to just pass the shape as an object to the subroutine (which eventually will be very complicated.)

```
Option Explicit    
Sub Main2()

Dim testPath As String
testPath = "a long path string"

'=> this next line sets the value of wPPTX which is a Global for a PowerPoint.Presentation
OpenPowerPointToEdit (testPath) 

Dim slideN As Slide
Dim shp1 As PowerPoint.Shape

Set slideN = wPPTX.Slides(1)

        Set shp1 = slideN.Shapes(1)
        MsgBox (shp1.Type & shp1.Name) '=> works fine
        UpdateShape2 (shp1) ' => Fails with "Object does not support this property or method"

End Sub
'=========================================================
Sub UpdateShape2(shp1 As PowerPoint.Shape)

MsgBox (shp1.Type)

End Sub
```

Comment: Try without the brackets i.e. `UpdateShape2 shp1`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27054151/passing-objects-as-parameters-in-excel-vba

Comment: That indeed works

Comment: In general, you don't need `()` if you are just calling the sub/method. so `MsgBox (shp1.Type & shp1.Name)` can actually be `MsgBox shp1.Type & shp1.Name` (it works fine because both `Type` and `Name` property returns a `String`, a non-object.

Comment: Same goes for `OpenPowerPointToEdit`